# Bond syndicates and systemic risk

Tags: bonds, risk, model, networks

I'm looking at both bond syndicates (groups of banks underwriting bond issuance), and also the holders of those bonds (groups of investors that hold those bonds for some time, potentially selling them on at some point).

I understand that when a bond needs to be sold for some reason, for example some criteria on using the money isn't met such as with a green bond going vanilla due to a referendum, this can trigger a contagion effect where other bond holders sell.

How much understanding is there of systemic risk in these situations? A complex network of dependencies can be formed between underwriters, holders, or the bonds themselves, and links represent dependencies between then derived from data.

I can see liability networks where loans are provided between actors (see [Systemic Risk in Financial Networks: A Survey, Jackson and Pernoud, 2012](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.12702.pdf)), and insolvency leads to a spread of insolvency, but when we have shared holdings of bonds, how is systemic risk understood in this setting? Is there any research on this?